# Trigger event is not working in touch devices

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, eventtrigger

I've this following JS code, it's working perfectly in the desktop but it's not working in the touch devices.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#gallery_trigger").click(function () {
    jQuery(".my-second-portfolio").trigger( "click");
  });  

});
```

From my analysis, I figured that following line of code is not working

```
jQuery(".my-second-portfolio").trigger( "click");
```

I understand that **.trigger( "click");** is not appropriate for the touch devices, so could you please help me to work this code in all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Try 'tap' or 'vclick'

http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

```
$(".my-second-portfolio").tap();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm using jQuery mobile frame work so do you have an alternate solution.

Comment: @FRSTAR Are you using JQuery Mobile or not? Above you say you are, yet in reply to my answer you say you are not.

Comment: No, I don't use jQuery mobile

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate. Because of this $(document).ready() will trigger before your first page is loaded and every code intended for page manipulation will be executed after a page refresh. This can be a very subtle bug. On some systems it may appear that it works fine, but on others it may cause erratic, difficult to repeat weirdness to occur.

Classic jQuery syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

To solve this problem (and trust me this is a problem) jQuery Mobile developers created page events. In a nutshell page events are events triggered in a particular point of page execution. One of those page events is a pageinit event and we can use it like this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {

});
```

To execute a code that will only available to the index page we could use this syntax:

```
$('#index').on('pageinit', function() {

});
```

There's also another special jQuery Mobile event and it is called mobileinit.When jQuery Mobile starts, it triggers a mobileinit event on the document object. To override default settings, bind them to mobileinit. One of a good examples of mobileinit usage is turning off ajax page loading, or changing default ajax loader behavior.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
  //apply overrides here
});
```

Or you could use something like this:

```
$('div:jqmData(url="index.html")').on('pageshow',function(){
    // code to execute on that page
    //$(this) works as expected - refers the page
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but actually I'm not using Jquery mobile framework. My site is implemented with a normal jQuery plugin and responsive WP site, Therefore I'm looking for normal jQuery solution and my click and load code is working but only this **.trigger( "click")** event is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, my misunderstanding.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the html code for the elements you are trying to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `$('.my-second-portfolio')[0].click();` to simulate a mouse click on the actual DOM element (not the jQuery object), instead of using the .trigger() jQuery method.

Note: DOM Level 2 .click() doesn't work on some elements in Safari. You will need to use a workaround.

http://api.jquery.com/click/